# C++ - Constructor Where Parameters Are Used By Base Class' Constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a Car class that inherits a Vehicle class. Both the Car and Vehicle class takes in the parameter, 'wheels'. From my understanding of how inheritance works, the object Car would be constructed in two phases: Vehicle would construct first by calling its Constructor, followed by Car which would also call its constructor. My question is how would I write my Car's constructor when its parameters are being used by the Vehicle's constructor?

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(int wheels);
};

class Car {
public:
    Car(int wheels): Vehicle(wheels);
};
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to inherit from Vehicle:

Header file:

```
class Car: public Vehicle {
public:
    Car(int wheels);
};
```

Cpp file:

```
Car::Car(int wheels): Vehicle(wheels) {
}
```

Comment: What should car.cpp look like? Should it look something like Car::Car(int wheel) {}?

Comment: Yes, if you want to call Vehicle constructor in the header. Or you can have `Car::Car(int wheel):Vehicle(wheel) {}` in `cpp` and not mention Vehicle in header file constructor (declaration).

Comment: So in my .h file, I should have class Car { public: Car(int wheels);};

Answer (score 7):

You pass wheels to the Vehicle constructor, then handle the additional params in the Car constructor.

```
class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    Car(int otherParam, int wheels);
};

Car::Car(int otherParam, int wheels) : Vehicle(wheels) {
    //do something with other params here
}
```

Of course, you can have multiple other params and they don't need to be integers ;)

EDIT: I also forgot to inherit from vehicle in my initial example, thanks perreal for pointing that out.

Comment: Hm. Silly me. What should car.cpp look like? Should it look something like Car::Car(int wheel) {}?

Comment: The second part of the code I posted (starting with Car::Car...) would go into car.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Either inline:

```
Car(int wheels) : Vehicle(wheels) { }
```

Or out-of-line:

```
class Car : public Vehicle {
  Car(int); 
  // ...  
};

Car::Car(int wheels) : Vehicle(wheels) { }
```

Comment: What should car.cpp look like? Should it look something like Car::Car(int wheel) {}?

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly,

```
      class Car:public Vehicle{...
```

I am not sure what you mean by "how would I write myCars constructor"

```
      Vehicle(int wheels):m_Wheels(wheels)
      {
           // or m_Wheels = wheels;
      }
      ...
      Car(int wheels):Vehicle(wheels)
      {
             if(m_Wheels != 4)
                  fprintf(stdout, "Uh Oh");
      }
```

In this case the vehicle constructor is called and then the car constructor is called. Note that I can use m_Wheels in Car, as it was initialized in Vehicle.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
Car::Car(int wheels)
:Vehicle(wheels) 
{
 // Do Car constructor specific stuff here.
}
```

The `:Vehicle(wheels)` will pass the wheels parameter up the line to the Vehicle constructor, and it will construct in the order you describe.

Comment: Np. I think your "post code-fu" is just fine :) What should car.cpp look like? Should it look something like Car::Car(int wheel) {}?

Comment: That's exactly what I've got there, the precise implementation of the Car constructor.  The Vehicle constructor would much the same `Vehicle::Vehicle(int wheels) {/* do stuff */ }`.